# VBA: How can I determine the current path of a document where a macro is being called?

Tags: vba, ms-word

An external .NET program which I didn't program by myself and I do not have influance on its code calls a macro in a Word document. The macro is mine.

How can I let the macro to know where its containing document resides?

The approach with `ActiveDocument.Path` can't be used due to the danger of too many other already opened documents, so that the user could possibly change the focus on one of them.

Thanks for your answers in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> ActiveDocument.Path
> ```

Almost there:

```
ThisDocument.Path
```